# Can I use the execCommand undo to undo actions not performed with execCommand?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, undo-redo, execcommand

I'm trying to implement a WYSIWYG editor using [execCommand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla) (I know many WYSIWYG editors exist, but none of them are good enough for me). Now, everything is working fine, but if I try and use the `backColor` command, it doesn't seem to work.

What I thought of doing is simply set background CSS on an element, and somehow add it to the undo/redo queue, so <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> will change back the custom change.

Is anywhere to do it? or I'm limited to ONLY undo/redo exec commands?

I'm interested in a Chrome solution only, IE & FF are not supported.

Answer (score 0):

my anwser might not be the prettiest one but forks fine :)

i used

```
var undo = []; // array
var redo = [];
// to store the undo and redo data
// and added event listener to textarea

document.getElementById("textarea").oninput = function(){
    // do something
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7z6kow73/1/